# Why left and right borders on the TabControl are different?

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

I added TabControl object to my Form and here is what I've got(upper and left borders):
[image]

Seems good, but check out the lower border:
[image]

the same problem with right border, what is the matter, and is there any chance to fix this ?

Comment: How are you specifying your control placement? By coordinates? Anchors? Docking?

Comment: @Dour, by coordinates(.Location)